# TFTP: cannot send/recive file, showing Error: TFTP, Opcode: Error Code(5)

Tags: ubuntu, tftp, xinetd, tftpd

I am trying to send/receive a file using TFTP from the network switch to ubuntu(VirtualBox on Windows 10 Pro), but getting an error code 5

By following the steps mentioned below it seems like my localhost is working with TFTP server, I can send and receive the file using localhost:

```
/home/abc# tftp localhost

tftp> put test

Sent 16 bytes in 0.0 seconds

tftp> get test

Received 16 bytes in 0.0 seconds

root@abc:/home/abc# ls -l /var/lib/tftpboot/
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Sep  6 18:03 test
```

***When I used the command in the switch to send/receive the file then I get the error message:***

***Trivial File Transfer Protocol***

***Opcode: Error Code (5)***

***[Destination File: test]***

***Error code: Access violation (2)***

***Error message: Access violation***

***[Expert Info (Warning/Response): TFTP ERROR packet]***

***[TFTP ERROR packet]***

***[Severity level: Warning]***

***[Group: Response]***

***Would you please guide me on how to fix this issue?***

**https://icesquare.com/wordpress/how-to-setup-tftp-on-ubuntu/**

First, let’s install all the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp -y
```

Next, we need to create a configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
```

Put the following content into the file.

```
service tftp
{
   protocol = udp
   port = 69
   socket_type = dgram
   wait = yes
   user = nobody
   server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args = var/lib/tftpboot -s
   disable = no
}
```

In the server_args, I have var/lib/tftpboot, which represents the location of the tftp root, i.e., /var/lib/tftpboot. Notice that I skip the root /.

Now let’s change the ownership of the directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tftpboot
sudo chown -R nobody:nobody /var/lib/tftpboot
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/tftpboot
```

and start the TFTP service:

```
sudo service xinetd stop
sudo service xinetd start
```

Verify the TFTP is running correctly or not:

```
netstat -na | grep LIST | grep 69
You should see something like this:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:69              0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN
```

Test: Upload a file to TFTP Server
Now let’s test the TFTP server by logging into the server first:

tftp localhost
and upload a file:

```
tftp> put myfile.jpg
Sent 56733279 bytes in 5.7 seconds
Quit:
q
```

Make sure that file has been uploaded:

```
ls -l /var/lib/tftpboot
```

Test: Download a file from TFTP Server
Now, let’s go to a different directory and download the file we just upload.

```
cd some_other_directory
```

and log in to the tftp server again:

```
tftp localhost
```

and get the file:

```
tftp> get myfile.jpg
Received 56733279 bytes in 5.7 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, switch network IP and Ubuntu machine IP address was on a different network. The problem has been resolved by setting the static IP address of my Ubuntu machine, same network IP as a switch IP.